# Importance of database name length

Tags: database, security

When setting up a database (e.g. in MySQL), how important is the length of the database name?

Is there any (measurable) difference between like `my_database_has_a_really_long_name` and `my_db`?

Especially regarding **security** and **performance of queries**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Databases often have limits on character length of name values and my cPanel MySQL has a limit of 16 characters.

2) The only other reason for the name is to identify the database. You should be able to identify the database with 16-32 characters.

There is no impact on performance of queries or securities with different names because

i) Performance of queries means that if the length of the database name is effecting performance - well - it's just not going to happen, it's a static string reference of alphanumeric characters. That's it. Processors deal with millions/billions of bits a second, every second, to add a few extra bits to this call is absolutely negligible.

ii) Security wise, the name of the database should never be anywhere near being given out to either the browser or the end user. If there is a security issue involving the name, it's because you've been breached regardless of how long your database name is.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a short, meaningful database name. It only identifies your database. The length is important if it might breach some limits, but query performance will not be affected by it, nor security. If one already has a connection to the database, then he/she can get the database names anyway with the

```
show databases;
```

command. So, your schema will help your performance. You need a good database password to have security and you need to encrypt user passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL version 5, MySQL includes a database called [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) which contains all database-, table-, and column-names a user has access to.

So even if an attacker cannot execute `show databases` as suggested by [@Lajos Arpad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29255257/1148035), because they don't have a direct connection, but only an SQL injection, they can get all database names to which they have access anyways.

For previous versions of MySQL, creating a database with a harder to guess name might have added a tiny bit of security. For example, if an attacker had an SQL injection in the database `boring_stuff`, and guessed the database name `user` (with the relevant tables, etc), renaming the database to `something_secret` might have prevented the attacker from accessing it. But so would better access control (creating separate database users for `boring_stuff` and `something_secret`), which would be preferable to security by obscurity.

**tl;dr**: No, long database names never really increased security, and they definitely don't since MySQL5, since all database names are accessible to all database users that have access to them. The same goes for table and column names.